# PlatformIO : Undefined reference to … const! Why?

Tags: esp32, platformio

I’am having trouble with const data.

It should be easy, but…

(working with ESP32 on PlatformIO)

This is OK:

```
*main.cpp*
const char test[] = { 1,2,3 };

main() {
   char buff[10];
   strcpy(buff, (char *) test);
}
```

…but if the const data are on another file, linker returns Undefined Reference to test:

```
*main.cpp*
extern const char test[];

main() {
   char buff[10];
   strcpy(buff, (char *) test);
}

--------------------------

*file.cpp*
const char test[] = { 1,2,3 };
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: your cpp is not included in the build. it is not compiled and not added added to linker command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must include the file where you define your variables

Here is an example:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <pathTo/file.cpp>

main() {
   char buff[10];
   strcpy(buff, (char *) test);
}
```

**file.cpp**

```
#ifndef file_cpp
#define file_cpp

const char test[] = { 1,2,3 };

#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

This bugged me also!
It seems that in C++ const variables not always get realized. To force a variable to be realized, add 'extern' also to its definition:

```
*file.cpp*
extern const char test[] = { 1,2,3 };
```

Worked for me on platform.io + ESP32